# Spring security throwing 401 error with valid client id and client secret

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, http-status-code-401

I have a spring boot 2 app REST endpoint as below

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/deleteUser", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity deleteUser(HttpServletRequest pRequest,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) String userId) {
    if (validateRequest(userId)) {
        try {
            response = myService.deleteUser(userId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception");
        }
    } else {
        response = new ResponseEntity("Invalid user request.", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    return response;
}
```

App doesnt have the basic auth enforced but restriction on endpoint.
Client is invoking the url with valid credentials:

```
deleteUserUrl=https://xxxx,clientId=xxxx,clentSecret=xxx
```

getting the error:

```
Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

here is my WebSecurityConfig file. This access is restricted to only certain role.

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
  public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSEALSecurityConfig
 {

    @Value("${ldap.server.admin.group}")
    private String SERVER_ADMIN_GROUP;

    @Value("${app.user.group}")
    private String APP_GP_USER;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler; 
    //This class just to capture 401 error

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
           httpSecurity
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole(SERVER_ADMIN_GROUP)
             .antMatchers("/test/deleteUser").hasRole(APP_GP_USER)
             .and().addFilterBefore(getCmpAuthenticationSelectionFilter(), 
             BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
              .httpBasic()
              .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
             .and().csrf().disable()
            . sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
         }
     }
```

Here is my CORS filter class:

```
@Configuration
public class CORSConfig {
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {    
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
  plugins {
     id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
     id 'java'
  }

  apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
  apply plugin: 'jacoco'
  apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
  apply plugin: 'jdepend'

  sourceCompatibility = 1.11

  dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    implementation "com.company:webauth-plugin:2.0.1"
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc') {
       exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
    }

    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0')
    compile group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '1.0.9'
    compile group: 'net.sf.jt400', name: 'jt400-jdk8', version: '9.5'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4')
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtime('com.microsoft:sqljdbc4:4.0')

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit'

 }
```

application.properties file:

```
  app.environment=${APP_ENV}
  server.servlet.context-path=${SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH}
  server.port=${SERVER_PORT}

  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
  management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
  management.health.ldap.enabled=false
  management.endpoints.web.cors.allow-credentials=true
```

Please note: This stopped working after made below changes in the app:

1. Introduction of CORSConfig class
2. Removing the gradle dependency

   ```
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-ldap', version: '5.1.2.RELEASE'
   ```
3. Included AuthEntryPoint class to capture 401 error

Please advice what I am doing wrong here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a 401 error. That means the url you are trying to access is protected. Since, you are saying you have provided valid user credentails, then maybe the user does not have the role "APP_GP_USER"?

I see that you are passing in sensitive information like client id/client secret as part of the request url. You should probably re-look at that.

Is the client passing in the Authorization header in the delete request? You need to provide this as you have enabled basic authentication in your WebSecurityConfig file through httpBasic() in the configure method.

I would suggest you to test your urls using a http client like postman.

For example, here I am trying to access a protected url: http://localhost:8088/demo/home without providing basic auth. Notice, I get a 401 error.

[401 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2sVH.png)

And here, I have provided proper credentials and so get back a proper response. Notice how postman added the Authorization header.

[Added basic auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrMeE.png)

[Success response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRIDL.png)

Comment: Thanks for the hint Naveen, I added .httpBasic().disable() so that api should not enforce basic auth and included CustomAccessDeniedHandler to capture 403 errors since httpbasic is disabled we shouldnt expect 401. I requested UI team to pass in role in the url to verify this